# Create a Project from Maven in command

Tags: maven

Why use the following code error occurs?

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=dotin -DartifactId=CleintServerApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

pleas help me?

Comment: Please provide the commandline output!

Comment: Replace CleintServerApp by ClientServerApp ?
Show both the pom.xml and the error you get.

Comment: Using maven 2.2.1 (Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)) it works for me...